# Getting the name of JSONArray as a string android

Tags: android

Hi, I have a JSONObject that has multiple arrays in it. I want to get the name of each array as a string does anyone know how I can do this?

Here's how my json looks. so the value I'm trying to get out is the name of the array so B or C in this case. the purpose of this is to set the text of a header on a list view to this value.

```
{"Contacts": //JSONObject
  {
    "B"://JSONArray..
    [
        {"ContactName":sdfsdf,"ID":900,"Number":1368349}, 
        {"ContactName":adsdfd,"ID":1900,"Number":136856},  
         {"ContactName":adglkhdofg,"ID":600,"Number":136845}
   ],
  "C":[
         {"ContactName":alkghoi,"ID":900,"Number":1368349},
         {"ContactName":wetete,"ID":1900,"Number":136856}, 
         {"ContactName":dfhtfh,"ID":600,"Number":136845}
     ]
      .....//and so on.. 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JSONObject method `names()` to return an array of the string names in the object.

Comment: thanks do you know how i can sort these into alphabetical order

Comment: JSONArray does not seem to support sorting. I'd iterate through the objects in the array, putting each string in a list. Then sort the list.